# QGIS Unable To Load Processing, Vector Tools and Plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, windows, loading

I am currently facing an issue with QGIS 3.8.3. In which I am unable to use Vector Tools and other plugins. [image: Missing Vector Tools]

Below are some of the trackbacks for the Python error. I am unable to show all due to the word count when posting the question:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'processing' 

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 312, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 25, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 32, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 54, in 
    from processing.algs.qgis.QgisAlgorithmProvider import QgisAlgorithmProvider  # NOQA
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\QgisAlgorithmProvider.py", line 76, in 
    from .HypsometricCurves import HypsometricCurves
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\HypsometricCurves.py", line 25, in 
    import numpy
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\jerom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in 
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\jerom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in 
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.8.3-Zanzibar Zanzibar, 685d8b15d2 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/jerom/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/jerom/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.8\bin\python37.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.8\bin
C:\Users\jerom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
C:\Users\jerom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\jerom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\jerom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/jerom/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\jerom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\IPython\extensions
C:\Users\jerom\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
```

I have re-installed QGIS many times and I am still facing this issue.

Any help or advice for this?

Comment: how are you installing QGIS? are you installing the 32 or 64 bit version?

Comment: @IanTurton Hi Ian! Thank you for your reply!

I am installing the 64 bit Standalone version of QGIS.

Comment: I was wondering if any pip installs of python modules via the Command Prompt could have resulted in this error.

I did install python modules like numpy, sklearn and mlrose for my other python projects yesterday before opening QGIS today and discovering this issue.

Comment: it looks like it is trying to run the 64bit version as a 32 bit program - **how are you installing qgis?**

Comment: Hi @IanTurton ! Thank you for your reply!
I am installing it via the QGIS homepage, the 64-bit Standalone version to be exact

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this problem by re-installing numpy. This seems to the problem here, as well : `File "C:\Users\jerom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py"`. I guess there is a 32 bit numpy installation somewhere.

Go to OsGeo4w Shell and type `py3_env`. You should see Python variables. Then type `pip uninstall numpy` and `pip install numpy`.

PS. OsGeo4W shell is accessible from the same application folder as QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by installing the 32bit version of QGIS.

Comment: Beware : https://blog.qgis.org/2020/10/15/phasing-out-32-bit-support-in-qgis/